# Dequeue Table of Content font

Tags: plugins

I have been using Table of Contents plugin on my website. It is slowing my site but I don't want to remove TOC from my site. Is there any way to dequeue [TOC fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5398.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_ez_icomoon', 11 );
function dequeue_ez_icomoon() {
    wp_deregister_style( 'ez-icomoon' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'ez-toc' );
    wp_register_style( 'ez-toc', EZ_TOC_URL . "assets/css/screen.min.css", array(), ezTOC::VERSION );
}
```

Comment: I am using Code Snippets plugin to insert this code but after adding the code, the font is still loading while testing using GTMetrix.

Comment: See edited code.

Comment: Thank you, the code is working well but a small problem, the TOC icon is not loading https://i.imgur.com/UNst7s8.png
Thank you Again :)

Comment: In fact this font contains only two icons, nothing else, and file size is about 1k. Plus 369 bytes in related css. So I'm not sure this impacts your site performance.

Comment: Actually not, the page speed is good but I wanted to reduce 1 request. Thank you.